# Error calling Dispatchers.setMain() in unit test

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, kotlinx.coroutines

Have started to try to use `kotlinx-coroutines-test` (https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/core/kotlinx-coroutines-test/README.md) in JUnit unit test but getting following error when i call `Dispatchers.setMain()`

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: TestMainDispatcher is not set as main dispatcher, have Main[missing, cause=java.lang.AbstractMethodError: kotlinx.coroutines.test.internal.TestMainDispatcherFactory.createDispatcher()Lkotlinx/coroutines/MainCoroutineDispatcher;] instead.

    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestDispatchers.setMain(TestDispatchers.kt:22)
```

I've tried calling `Dispatchers.setMain(Dispatchers.Unconfined)` and also passing in `val mainThreadSurrogate = newSingleThreadContext("UI thread")`.  It looks like issue isn't anyway with value being passed in but rather it's tripping up in `mainDispatcher` test in following

```
public fun Dispatchers.setMain(dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher) {
    require(dispatcher !is TestMainDispatcher) { "Dispatchers.setMain(Dispatchers.Main) is prohibited, probably Dispatchers.resetMain() should be used instead" }
    val mainDispatcher = Dispatchers.Main
    require(mainDispatcher is TestMainDispatcher) { "TestMainDispatcher is not set as main dispatcher, have $mainDispatcher instead." }
    mainDispatcher.setDispatcher(dispatcher)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out issue was I was using older version of `kotlinx-coroutines-core` dependency.  When I updated to v1.1.0 it worked (thanks @vigit for helping trigger that realisation!)

Comment: should've accepted @yigit's answer, you didn't have to create a new one and accept your own. js.

Comment: As mentioned in my reply above, the issue in my case was *not* that that dependency wasn't present but that I was using older version....that other answer prompted me to realise that.

Answer (score 17):

Try adding core as a dependency on your test. It solved the problem for me.

`testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.1.0")`

Comment: Thanks @yigit ....so, I had that as normal `implementation` dependency already.....but your answer made me notice that I wasn't using version 1.1....I updated to that and it worked!

Comment: Had the same problem. Was using different core and test versions. Using same 1.1.0 versions solved the error.