# Getting error on using classes from kotlinx-coroutine-test

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

It seems like *kotlinx-coroutines-test* dependency is not working for me as I can't access members of the dependency like `TestCoroutineDispatcher`, `setMain()`, `resetMain()` etc. I was following this [doc](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/) but can't access the members despite adding the gradle dependency. I tried rebuilding the project and invalidating the cache and restart but nothing seems to work. I have also tried doing `androidExtensions {experimental = true}` but still no luck.

*build.gradle*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.kotlincoroutines"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.1.1'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.1.1'


    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha03'

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    // ViewModel and LiveData
    def lifecycle_version = '2.0.0-beta01'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.1.0-alpha02"
    testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$lifecycle_version"

    // Room for database
    def room_version = '2.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    def work_version = "1.0.0-rc01"
    implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:$work_version"

    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:0.42"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$lifecycle_version"

    testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.3.0-M1'
}
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: _Unresolved reference: TypeCoroutineDispatcher_

Comment: Nevermind the bounty, I imported the dependency for the wrong module :-/

Comment: Why did you need `experimental = true`?  Seems like that is not related to Coroutines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your library version to `1.3.2` instead of `1.3.0-M1` like so:

```
testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.3.2'
```

And be sure that your tests are `unit test` in the `test` folder, not `instrumented test` in `androidTest` folder.

Comment: I updated my library version but it still didn't work

Comment: Please check that you use it in unit tests, not instrumented test @ARYAN

Answer (score 17):

replacing testImplementation  with implementation did the trick for me.

Comment: please check that you use androidTestImplementation but not testImplementation

Answer (score 0):

just add :-

> testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.1.0")

Source :- Here yigit have given solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54061885/error-calling-dispatchers-setmain-in-unit-test) and ssems like working .

Answer (score 0):

Try adding core as a dependency on your test. It solved the problem for me.

```
testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.1.0")
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution from @Squti worked for me, namely moving the class trying to import the TestCoroutineDispatcher from a package in the `src` directory to a package in the `test` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Change "testImplementation" to  "implementation"

```
def coroutines_version  = "1.6.4"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:$coroutines_version"
```

Then in the test class you can use it like

```
@Test
fun insertUser() = runTest{

}
```